# Anyone know why pg.K_LEFT is the number 1073741904?

Tags: pygame

So this is not a problem specifically, but i thought it is a bit weird. Why is pg.K_LEFT the number 1073741904 (and any other arrow key on the keyboard is strangely long)? An example of what i mean:

```
import pygame
pg = pygame
pg.init()
screen = pg.display.set_mode((800,600))

run = True
while run:

    screen.fill((0,0,0))
    for e in pg.event.get():
        if e.type == pg.QUIT:
            run = False

        if e.type == pg.KEYDOWN:
            if e.key == 1073741904:
                print("pressing arrow key left")

    pg.display.flip()
```

Running this piece of code and pressing the left arrow key prints that you pressed the left arrow key. But why is it this long number, not something shorter? Also where can i ask these questions because i know everybody hates questions that are not a problem. I will edit the post if needed. Thanks

Comment: What is wrong with 1073741904. It is just a constant. PyGame uses SDL under the hood and the codes come from there.

Comment: That is `0x40000050` in hex, looks pretty regular

Answer (score 2):

That value in hexadecimal (convenient byte representation, having 2 hex digits corresponding to *exactly* 8 bits) is `4000 0050h` where perhaps it seems far less "random".

You should not in any event use literals (decimal or hex) for this.  Pygame defines symbolic constants for all keys.  See https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/key.html.  In this case `K_LEFT`.

The *binary structure* of these values is important since it allows *modifiers* to be applied by bitwise OR-ing the base key values with modifiers such that for example <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>←</kbd> would be `K_LEFT | KMOD_CTRL | KMOD_SHIFT`.

Without reference to all the values, I would imagine that if you look at the codes, regular character keys are all 8 bit significant digits, the 40h in the LSB (or rather bit 30 alone) is a modifier indicating a non-printing control key perhaps.  Note that these values are not thew same across versions of Pygame - another reason not to use the literal value.

In fact I took a look, the basic (unmodified) key codes are defined (weirdly in decimal) at https://github.com/pygame/pygame/blob/main/src_c/key.c.